# Let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. For each n, let $I_n$ be the open interval cenetered at $r_n$ of radius $2^{-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

Let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. For each n, let $I_n$ be the open interval cenetered at $r_n$ of radius $2^{-n}$ and let $U = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$. Prove that $U$ is a proper, open, dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and that $U^c$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Attempt :

Its a countable union of open sets and hence is open.

Given a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ any $\epsilon$ ball containing $x$ would contain a rational number hence $U$ is dense.

How do you prove $U$ is proper, $U^c$ is nowhere dense ?

There is a partial answer in mathstackexchange which I am not able to understand

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10093

Answer (score 6):

The (Lebesgue) measure of $U$ is bounded above by $\mu(U) \le \sum_n \mu(I_n) = \sum_n \frac{2}{2^n} = 2\sum_n \frac{1}{2^n} \le 2$. So $U$ is proper as its measure is not $\infty$.

*added on request*
If you haven't studied Lebesgue measure yet: for every $n$ pick successive non-empty closed subsets $C_n$ with $C_{n+1} \subset C_n$ such that $\operatorname{diam}(C_n) \le 4r_n$ and $C_n \cap I_n = \emptyset$ this can be done as $\operatorname{diam}(I_n) = 2r_n$, so there is always room for the next $C_{n+1}$ if we have already defined $C_n$ to avoid $I_{n+1}$. Then Cantor's theorem (see [the complete metric variant here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem)) about decreasing closed subsets of decreasing-to-$0$ diameters in a complete metric space (proof summary: pick $x_n \in C_n$ show it is Cauchy, and its limit is in) the intersection of the $C_n$ is non-empty and misses $\cup_n I_n$ by construction. As an historical aside: Cantor used this theorem originally to see that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and is his first proof of this fact. Here we avoid an enumeration of open intervals that keep getting smaller and smaller fast, he avoided $r_n$ for a supposed enumeration $r_n$ of $\mathbb{R}$ to get a non-enumerated real...

$U$ is dense as $\mathbb{Q} \subset U$.

The complement of an open and dense set is closed and nowhere dense: Suppose $O \subseteq U^c$,were open and non-empty, then it would have to contain some rational, but these are all in $U$, not in $U^c$. So $\operatorname{int}(U^c) = \emptyset$, which is enough to show nowhere denseness for closed sets.

Similarly define $U_k$ as $U$ only using $\frac{1}{k}2^{-n}$ as radius around $q_n$, then a similar computation shows that $\mu(U_k) \le \frac{2}{k}$ ,the $U_k$ are still open and dense, and so $D:= \cap_k U_k$ has measure $0$ while $D^c = \cup_k (U_k)^c$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets, hence is of first category (a.k.a "meagre"). This shows that we can write $\mathbb{R}$ as the union of two "small sets", one small in measure (measure $0$), the other small in "category" (meagre). For more exploration of differences and anlogies between these concepts, see Oxtoby's classical booklet "Measure and category" which starts with this example, in fact.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am an undergraduate student who has not been introduced to lebesgue measure ....this problem appears in baire category theory chapter of a metric space book

Comment: @spaceman_spiff I'll think about a more elementary way to see properness.

Comment: @spaceman_spiff I came up with an alternative proof based on completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, see edit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your construction of the "nested closed interval". Especially $r_n$ is the centre, not the radius.

Comment: @Beginner The $r_n$ are the diameters of the $C_n$, so neither the radii nor the centres. We can just take unions of sufficiently small closed intervals.