# Let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. For each $n$, let $I_n$ be the open interval centered at $r_n$ with length $2^{-n}$ ...

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. For each $n$, let $I_n$ be the open interval centered at $r_n$ with length $2^{-n}$, and let $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$. Prove that $U$ is a proper, open, dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and that $U^{c}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Hi, I'm in my first analysis class and working on this problem and could use some help/explanation. I can show that $U$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ without any issues, but I can't figure out how to show that it is a proper subset (even though it clearly must be). I found this question as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230377/let-r-n-be-an-enumeration-of-mathbbq-for-each-n-let-i-n-be-the-open), but I didn't understand how they were showing that $U$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So I guess what I'm looking for is some explanation or an alternative proof.

I also don't understand how $U^{c}$ can be empty since the "size" of $U$ is 1 (the sum of the lengths of the intervals used in construction). Any clarification is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $U=\mathbb R$. Then $[0,2]\subseteq \bigcup I_n$. By compactness $[0,2]$ is covered by a  finite number of these intervals. I will leave it to you to check that an interval of length $2$ cannot be covered by a  finite number of intervals whose total length is less than $\sum \frac1 {2^{N}}=1$.

Suppose the closed set $U^{c}$ contains an interior point. Then there exist $a<b$ such that $(a,b) \subseteq U^{c} \subseteq \mathbb Q^{c}$. This means the interval $(a,b)$ contains no rational number. This contradiction proves that $U^{c}$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: Thanks, that actually clears it up a lot!